# Recorded videos from Iphone is playing in upper left corner in jwplayer

Tags: iphone, video, jwplayer

I have integrated jwplayer in my website to play videos. All videos working fine instead of those videos that recorded by I-phone. If videos recorded by iphone then it is playing in upper left corner. I have searched alot but didn't got any clue why it happening. Please help..!!

Answer (score 1):

Run the video through Handbrake with its default options, plus check "Web optimized." That will cure this issue.

http://handbrake.fr/

(Edit: BTW, this problem occurs when the phone is held in portrait mode instead of landscape mode. The orientation flags in the video are screwed up.)

Comment: Indeed, if a smartphone video is recorded in portrait mode, it has this issue.